# Scala akka http server - print POST messages

Tags: scala, http, post, akka

I have a simple scala server that listens on localhost:9000, and I want to print the body of each post message I get.

When I send a post message to localhost:9000 I get the "Hello, World!". I want to print the actual data that was sent in the POST body message.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object Main extends App {
  val host = "0.0.0.0"
  val port = 9000
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("helloworld")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  def route = path("hello") {
    post {
      println("we got a post message!")
      complete("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
  Http().bindAndHandle(route, host, port)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is just extracting data from post request. For example;

```
...
def route = path("hello") {
     post {
          entity(as[String]) { str =>
               println(str)
               ... // do stg
          }
     }
}
...
```

You can take a look at [this page](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/marshalling-directives/entity.html). I hope it helps!

Comment: This will work until there if there are no `ToEntityMarshaller` that want to unmarshall `String` to `JsonString`. This can happen when using `ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport` and `import io.circe._`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extract request with directive `extractRequest`, convert the entity to `Strict`. And `map` and `onComplete` to the `Future`

```
def route = path("hello") {
  post {
    extractRequest {req =>
      req.entity.toStrict(2.seconds).map(_.data.utf8String).onComplete(println)
      complete("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
}
```